# XML Documents and Schema Element import and complex data types

Tags: xml, schema

I am just venturing into the realm of XML and I would like some guidance regarding the following please:

When creating my XML document based on a schema in Eclipse I have given an option to choose an element on which my XML document is going to be based.

Is the possible to import/link more than one element from a schema file?

Also is it possible to import complex data types instead of elements in the XML document? And also import multiple data types?

Many thanks for your time.

**Result:** Thank you all for the knowledge and apologies for not constructing a properly question.

Comment: Generally yes, to all your questions. But, it depends on which components you are working with. Can you provide more details about what software components you use and what you try to accomplish?

Comment: I am using Eclipse to construct XML Schema and XML document based on the schema. Could you please provide a URL where it states that importing complex data types is possible? As well as importing multiple complex data types? Thank you.

Comment: Your question seems hard to understand, because XSD mainly *is* the idea of using complex and simple data types. Maybe this will help you along the way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468549.aspx Also, you should know which Eclipse component provides you with the XSD and XML editor functionality, because there are many different implementation available. However, what you are asking seems to be more of a topic of the XSD standard itself. Take look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/ http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/xsdeditor/ Tschau!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Eclipse, which perhaps explains why I don't fully understand what you mean.

> Is the possible to import/link more than one element from a schema file?

Any global element declaration (that is, an xs:element with a name attribute appearing as a child of xs:schema) can be used as the root element of your instance document, if this is what you mean.

> Also is it possible to import complex data types instead of elements in the XML document?

Any global type definition (that is, an xs:simpleType or xs:complexType with a name attribute appearing as a child of xs:schema) can be used as the value of the `xsi:type` attribute in your instance document, if this is what you mean.

Comment: Regarding: Also is it possible to import complex data types instead of elements in the XML document? Your understanding is correct. I was concerned thinking only elements can be imported from a Schema definition file; when constructing and XML document based on several Schemas?

Comment: constructing and XML: a not and.

Comment: You can create a new XML Schema file, and import (inherit) all Schema "items" that you want, for later use in your XML instance documents (recommended). Or you import multiple XML schema files into individual XML namespaces inside your XML instance documents.